# What's the meaning of "という" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading about this grammar in my book but I don't get it. According to the book it means - そうだ　and - らしい. Here is an example:

**UPDATE**:　Full Sentence:

> 従来、病院といえば白い壁が基調の空間であった。　しかし、白くて冷たい壁を見ていると　人はゆううつな感じになり、不安を覚えるという。　この環境では、患者は快復への意志を高めることはできない。

It says that it is used at the end of a written sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

という just means what it always means. と is the quoting particle and いう means "to say". In your example sentence, maybe "It is said that..." would be a fitting translation, i.e.

> 従来、病院といえば白い壁が基調の空間であった。
>   Up to now, a hospital was thought of a space with white walls.
>
> しかし、白くて冷たい壁を見ていると人はゆううつな感じになり、不安を覚えるという。
>   But by looking at a white, cold wall, it is said that people start getting depressed and feeling uneasy.
>
> この環境では、患者は快復への意志を高めることはできない。
>   In this environment the patient can't increase his desire for recovery.

"It is said that" is quite close to the nuance of らしい or そうだ, like your textbook points out.